# Getting Jest error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match') when using useParams in the component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs

Jest Test File:

```
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import Browse from '@pages/Home/Browse/index'

describe('Browse test suite', () => {
  it('Browse should render correctly', () => {
    const component = shallow(<Browse />)
    expect(component).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

Part of my Component:

```
interface IParamTypes {
  nodeId: string
}
const Browse = () => {
  const { nodeId } = useParams<IParamTypes>()
  .....
}
```

Error when I am running the Test Case:

```
● Browse test suite › Browse should render correctly

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')

  13 | }
  14 | const Browse = () => {
> 15 |   const { nodeId } = useParams<IParamTypes>()
           ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to render your component in isolation, which means you don't have access to the `useParams` object. I'm not sure how to do this with Enzyme, but here is how it works with Testing Library, which I believe should work with Enzyme also.

Try to wrap your component in your test suit with a router and pass the history object as a prop:

```
import {createMemoryHistory} from 'history'
const BrowseWithRouter = () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    return (
        <Router history={history}>
            <Browse />
        </Router>
    )
};
```

Then shallow render your new component:

```
const component = shallow(<BrowseWithRouter />)
```